# Reading a text file that is delimited by a newline. C++ on unix

Tags: c++, file, unix, file-io, fstream

Ok I have tried many different suggestions on the www, and came up flat with all the examples. This is such a simple thing that is not working for me it is frustrating! I have attached the file that I need to read into a data structure. In the example I am just printing it to the screen. This following code has worked for me before, but now isn't. I have tried in visual studios, and on unix, and neither are running it. I ultimately need it to run on unix.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working, or suggest a better way to read in my file?
Example file:

```
word
book
programming
```

Here is my function to read in the file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "words.txt"
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ifstream file;
string line;

file.open("words.txt");
if(file.is_open()){
    while(getline(file, line)){
        getline(file, line);
        cout << line <<endl;
    }
}
file.close();



return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

the file but is throwing errors about delimiters. For example in unix running with g++ :

```
wordlist2.txt: 498841:1: error: missing terminating ' character
  incumbent's
  ^
wordlist2.txt:498875:13 warning: missing terminating ' character [enabled by default] 
  at your wits' end
  ^
```

And in visual studios:

```
  Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does                not support default-int    
  Error 14  error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mouse'
```

Comment: On which operating system are you running this? And what is the output? **Use a debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: If you could add just a little bit more to the example to make it into a fully compilable, runnable example, it would help you get a high quality answer.

Comment: `#include "words.txt"` seriously? Remove that, it is what is causing those syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!file.eof())
```

Is not a good idea. Write the following instead:

```
while (getline(file, line)) {
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

You certainly don't want to

```
#include "words.txt"
```

Remove this line!!

Comment: THX for fixing the typo ;)

Comment: I tried this change and it is still throwing the same exceptions.

Comment: @user3342236 The errors you get are about including the text file, see my update. Though it's still a bad idea to test for `std::ifstream::eof()`.

Comment: WOW! that fixed it. Thank you. So I don't have to include it, but it does have to be in the same directory?

Comment: @user3342236 No, you have to put in the proper path. (If it is in the same directory, just name is enough, otherwise `path/to/the/file.txt` is what you want.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you. Something so simple.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am not telling him to include it, I am telling him to use the proper path to the file in opening it and that is enough. (Read the comment as "No, it does not have to be in the same directory, you just have to put in the proper path...") (And just now I can see the little typo :-) ) Also see my comment on the question proper.